# Default Asp Net Core React Redux template blank screen

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created a default asp-net core 3.1 project with React and Redux using visual studios provided template via the below window:
[image]

Without changing anything when I run the application (with or without debugging) I only get a white screen with a loading icon in the tab.
No errors in the console or debug output.

I've dug through the internet for a while now and cant seem to find the answer.